# Force div to next line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the "footer" div to sit below the "main" div, except it keeps appearing next to it. I just want it to sit directly below the preceding div (not be forced to the bottom), except it always seems to sit below the header.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            Heading
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            Content
        </div>
        <div class="footer">More details on how you can help coming soon.</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("./../img/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: OSWALD;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

.main{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 19px 22px 7px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "futura-pt", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

.contact{
    border-top: 6px solid #e2d056;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #e2d056;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 25px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 22px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "futura-pt", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use display: inline-block then. Would be nice if you could trim down your enormous css.

Comment: Just remove position property of main. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove `display: inline-block;` altogether since it doesn't appear to have a purpose.

If you still need the `display: inline-block;` you can use `.footer { clear: both; }` or do `.main { float: left; clear: both; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `postion:absolute` to `position:relative` for `.main` as absolute takes the div element out of the layout flow.

```
.main {
    position:relative;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/ewaLf4ct/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.footer { clear: both; }`.